# How can I make People.GetBatchGet() return photos of a certain size

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I'm currently using PeopleService.People.GetBatchGet() to return all the photos of the users in the provided batch. The method I'm using returns the photos with their size set to 100. I'm wondering if I could receive the photos with a different size.

```
// peopleService is an object of type PeopleServiceService

var connection = peopleService.People.GetBatchGet();
connection.PersonFields = "photos";
connection.ResourceNames = resourceNames;

var result = connection.Execute();
```

`result.Responses` is a List of `PersonResponse` objects.

So, for example, `result.Responses[0].Person.Photos[0].Url` will have a value like this: 'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/somecharacters/s100/photo.jpg'.

I've noticed that 's100' is actually the size for the picture, and if I'll modify it to another value, the picture from the url will have that size.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can make the method return the photos in a different size (maybe adding a parameter to `connection`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [peopleService.People.GetBatchGet()](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet) returns a person object which contains a photo object [photo](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Photo)

```
{
  "metadata": {
    object (FieldMetadata)
  },
  "url": string,
  "default": boolean
}
```

These images are in a standard size and can not be changed.  The api does not offer an option for changing the size of the image it returns.

YOu might considered adding it as a feature request on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:344199%2B